# how to learn svg: list of resources libraries tutorial

Tags: css, svg

i need something like on the picture to be resizable and editable.
Should i use css3 or svg?
Can u advice some library or tool to make things like that? 
[image]

Comment: Use d3.js for this.

Comment: Lalji, its not problem make div and give it border radius and then play with css3 transforms. But if in future i  need to add more components to this graph(picture). Its wasting of time making it by hand. So i ask some advise.

Comment: Ty, Arthem. I try it.

Answer (score -1):

Its better you go with svg.

1. Even add complex shapes in future.
2. Variety of framework available(D3.js)
3. Resize, edit, and color change is easy one
4. Works well even for larger scree.